# Androidplot: Dynamic plot with specific scan rate

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I am using androidplot that loops the showing of a pulse (essentially a relatively short sequence of points) `n` times per minute and a flat value the rest of the time. There is an erase bar at the start that removes the 50 oldest points. But what I can't figure out how to have that graph update at a specific interval (the delay in `run()`) so that the series scans at 25mm/sec.

```
private class PulseXYSeries implements XYSeries {

    private ArrayList<Integer> values;
    private String title;
    public  PulseXYSeries(String title, int size) {
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size;i++) {
            values.add(null);
        }
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void remove(int idx) {
        values.set(idx, null);
    }
    public void setY(int val, int idx) {
        values.set(idx, val);
    }
    @Override
    public Number getX(int idx) {
        return idx;
    }

    @Override
    public Number getY(int idx) {
        if(idx >= values.size())
            return null;
        return values.get(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return values.size();
    }

}

private class MonitorDataSource implements Runnable {
    private final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 1000;
    private boolean keepRunning = false;
    private List<Integer> queue;
    private int flat;
    private Thread rd;

    MonitorDataSource(View rootView) {
        queue = getSelectedPointData(rootView);
        flat = queue.get(0);
        rd = new Thread(/** runnable that calls dynamicPlot.redraw() at 30Hz  **/);
        rd.start();
    }
    public void stopThread() {
        keepRunning = false;
        rd.interrupt();
    }

   public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG,"Running pulse thread");
            keepRunning = true;
            int i=0;
            boolean pulsing = true;
            long lastPulse = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            long pulseDelay = 1000*60/mHeartRatePicker.getValue();
            int position = 0;
            // we need to scan at 25mm/sec
            long delay = 10;    
            DisplayMetrics dp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float plotWidth = dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getWidgetDimensions().canvasRect.width();
            float plotWidthMm = plotWidth / dp.xdpi * 25.4f;
            float widthPerTickInMm = plotWidthMm/(float)SAMPLE_SIZE;
            Log.i(TAG,"Width per tick: "+widthPerTickInMm+" plot width px="+plotWidth+" in mm="+plotWidthMm+" xdpi="+dp.xdpi+" xdpmm="+(dp.xdpi*(1.0f/25.4f)));
            long currTime,loopStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
            while (keepRunning) {
                // plot 4 points at a time
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if(pulsing) {
                        mMovingWaveSeries.setY(queue.get(i),position);
                        if(++i == queue.size()-1) {
                            pulsing = false;
                            i=0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        mMovingWaveSeries.setY(flat,position);
                        currTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        if(currTime - lastPulse >= pulseDelay) {
                            pulsing = true;
                            lastPulse = currTime;
                        }
                    }
                    mMovingWaveSeries.remove(((position + 50) % SAMPLE_SIZE));
                    position = (position+1) % SAMPLE_SIZE;
                    if(position +1 >= SAMPLE_SIZE) {
                        float diff = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - loopStart )/ 1000000000f;
                        loopStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
                        Log.i(TAG,"Looped through "+plotWidthMm+"mm in "+diff+"s = "+ (plotWidthMm/diff)  +"mm/s");
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(delay); 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure - you want the data to scroll across the screen at a rate of 25 millimeters per second?  If so, how close is the result of what you currently have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be lacking in your code is an instantaneous measurement of the current scan rate, in mm.  You can use this value to adjust the scale of your plot's domain to get the desired effect.  This is done via **XYPlot.setDomainBoundaries(...)**.  Domain scale and sample frequency (seemingly represented by "delay" in your code) can be adjusted to compensate for each other, so if you need to maintain a particular domain scale then modulate your sampling frequency accordingly.  If done properly, rendering frequency should not matter at all and can be allowed to float...in fact modulating refresh rate to compensate for sample rate will usually result in buffer overrun/underrun issues.

**UPDATE (response to below comment)**

Appears that you're actually throttling the datasource (sample rate), not the plot (refresh rate), which is fine.  The first thing you'll need to do is determine the loop frequency required to achieve 25mm/sec based on widthPerTickInMm and the number of points you are drawing in each loop:

**Frequency(Hz) = 25 / (widthPerTickInMm * pointsPerLoop)**

Use this value to modulate your datasource update loop.  Here's an example of how you can dynamically modulate an arbitrary loop at a given frequency:

```
       float hz = 5; // modulate at 5hz
       long budget = (long) ((1/hz) * 1000f);
       long loopDurationMs = 0;
       long loopStartMs = 0;
       while(true) {
           // calculate how long this loop took:
           long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
           loopDurationMs = now - loopStartMs;
           long sleepTime = budget - loopDurationMs;
           loopStartMs = now;
           if(sleepTime > 0) {
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
               }
           }
       }
```

Just a warning - I've not tried compiling or running the code but the concept is there. (This only works if your potential loop frequency is > desired frequency...probably obvious but just in case)

Comment: I don't want to adjust the domain boundaries as the plot loops back to the start when it gets to the end, so the boundaries never change. In my testing, it scans the width of the plot in ~5.2s. Also, calling `redraw()` repeatedly makes the GC run and I can't figure out where allocations are occurring in the androidplot source that might cause this.
I've solved it now by plotting 3 points every loop and achieved 24.5mm/s . Can you provide some code on how I can automatically adjust the delay or number of points plotted at each loop? I've updated my code.